# Getting "undefined" on trying to get hours from time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, time

I want to know, how can I fetch the hours and minutes value individually and where I am going wrong? please help me.

````
<ion-input type="time" [(ngModel)]="time"></ion-input>
<ion-button (click)="func(time)">Get Time</ion-button>

//.ts file
func(time:Time){
 console.log(time);
 console.log(time.hours);// Output = **undefined**
 console.log(time.minutes);//Output = **undefined**
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by below method:

```
func(time:Time){
timeSA= time.toString.spilt(":",2)
var timeA: number[]=[];
for(let item of timeSA){
 let no:number=Number(item);
 timeA.push(no);
}

console.log("hours",timeA[0]);
console.log("minutes",timeA[1]);
}
```